# Interpretación de la frase "Como la sombra huye la hora"

Tags: modismos, historia, tiempo, religión

El lema "Como la sombra huye la hora" está grabado en un reloj de sol que pertenecía a la Misión de Santa Cruz, en California. Parece un recordatorio al estilo de "*tempus fugit*". A lo mejor el reloj se fabricó en España.

La sombra que huye la hora cae de la vara del reloj, pero ¿qué es así como ella? ¿El texto implica otro sujeto no mencionado, o es parte de una frase más larga? ¿Cúal será su origen?

Comment: Mmmm. A mi me parece una especie de juego de palabras. Según pasa el día y se mueve el sol alrededor de la tierra (es coña, soy heliocentrista no geocentrista!) la posición de la sombra cambia. En un reloj de sol la sombra es además la hora, con lo cual estoy de acuerdo con que es una versión más poética de "tempus fugit". El tiempo y la sombra huyen juntos en un reloj de sol. No me parece un proverbio o modismo conocido. No entiendo por qué piensas que hay un sujeto no mencionado. Puedes aclarar por favor?

Comment: Yo creo que el sujeto queda más claro si le damos la vuelta a la frase: _La hora huye como la sombra._ Lo que se omite, más que el sujeto, es el perseguidor: ¿de qué huye la hora?

Comment: justo estaba escribiendo algo parecido cuando a aparecido el comentario de @Charlie. No se huye *algo* sino *de algo*, así que interpreto que sombra y hora huyen de la misma manera.

Comment: La misión de Santa Cruz la fundó Juan Crespí, uno de los seguidores de Junípero Serra. No es que el reloj se fabricara en España; es que los fundadores de la misión eran españoles y, en esa época, California pertenecía a la corona española.

Comment: No entiendo esta parte: "¿qué es como ella?"  Por favor, que alguien edite esa parte para que quede más clara.

Comment: @blonfu eso ahí fue mi malentendido. ¡gracias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La frase es más clara con una pausa en medio:

> Como la sombra, huye la hora.

Reordenando:

> La hora huye como la sombra.

En un sentido literal, la sombra que produce el Sol nunca se para, siempre está en movimiento aunque apenas se note. Lo mismo pasa con el tiempo.

En un sentido más figurado, tanto la sombra como el tiempo son imposibles de atrapar. Si intentas perseguirla, la sombra se mueve contigo, parece como si huyera de ti.

Con lo cual: sí, es otra manera de expresar el concepto *tempus fugit*, solo que aquí juegan con el hecho de que es un reloj de sol, y el tiempo, la hora, se mueve *literalmente* como la sombra.